# Angular 5 Routing from Password Reset Email

Tags: angular, azure, iis, angular5

I'm working on a password reset functionality using Angular 5 but I'm having issues getting IIS configured correctly to make it so my url is actually ran through the angular router.

The password reset email link looks something like `https://myapp.com/reset/<token>`

The angular route config is as follows

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  ... other routes ...
  { path: 'reset/:code', component: ResetPasswordComponent},
  { path: "**", redirectTo: 'home' }
])
```

and here is my web.config file. I found this listed online for hosting angular applications in azure

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="angular cli routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm just not sure what other rewrite rules I need to configure to have my password reset link work.  If I'm actually in the angular app and manually change the URL the routing works, but coming through a new window when clicking the link from email gives me this error

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: Try this: https://medium.com/@h.alhaj/angular-route-with-iis-shared-host-d8dfc80877c4